# Progress bar colors in Nuxt Project aren't showing in terminal on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: themes, gnome-terminal

I'm really new with Ubuntu. Everything was going well, but now I have this little problem.

I can't see the progress bars colors (see image). Before they had a green color for the client and orange for the server.

[image]

I'm using oh-my-zsh, starship and google dark theme for the terminal in Ubuntu 20.04. And for the gnome theme i'm using Dracula (the most recent change was changing the Dracula Theme).

The terminal should look similar to this picture:

[image]

Can you help me giving some ideas on how to solve this problem?

Comment: Before they had a green color for the client and orange for the server. What does this mean? When did they have a color? What have you done since?

Comment: As the picture below, the progress bar looked like that (Client->green, Server->orange). They had those colors normally, event after making all those changes (oh-my-zsh, starship and google dark theme in gnome). But now, and I don't really now why or what exactly happened, the colors for the progress bar aren't being showed. I 'm going to revert all these changes and see if I can see the colors again.

Comment: You never answered my question when did they have the colors a different version of Ubuntu? Before some update? Before you added some new program? If someone goes to the trouble of asking a question to try and help you answering it might be a good idea.

Comment: Maybe my english is not good enough to make myself clear. But I'll try again. What I meant is that I had a fresh install on Ubuntu and it that moment I could see the progress bar colors (when running a nuxt project). Then later I make all these changes, I installed oh-my-zsh, starship and google dark theme in the terminal. I also added the Dracula Gnome Theme. Even after all these changes, the colors were being showed correctly. Then after some time (and I don't know or don't remember what I did) the colors of the progress bar aren't being showed. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

OK guys. It wasn't an Ubuntu problem. Sorry about that. The thing was an environment variable `CI=true` was removing the colors from the progress bar when compiling the Nuxt project. I did not have idea that variable could affect the colors inside the terminal.